# run time of this Prime Factor function?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I wrote this prime factorization function, can someone explain the runtime to me? It seems fast to me as it continuously decomposes a number into primes without having to check if the factors are prime and runs from 2 to the number in the worst case.

I know that no functions yet can factor primes in polynomial time. Also, how does the run time relate asymptotically to factoring large primes?

```
function getPrimeFactors(num) {
    var factors = [];
    for (var i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
        if (num % i === 0) {
            num = num / i;
            factors.push(i);
            i--;
        }
    }
    return factors;
}
```

Comment: If I give you `8683317618811886495518194401279999999`, how long will it take your function to decide if it is prime?

Comment: You only need to test two and odd factors up to the square root of the number to be factored. For large numbers, that's quite a bit faster. (In fact, you only need to go up to the square root of what is yet to be factored, but that doesn't change the execution time for the worst case, which is prime numbers).

Comment: Actually, factoring primes in polynomial time is easy -- since they are prime, there is nothing to do (proving prime can be done by AKS test in polynomial time)!  The hard part is factoring composites.  The run time for factoring large composites, in the worst case, is bounded by the time for the [number field sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, if `num` is prime then it would take exactly `num - 1` steps. This would mean that the algorithm's runtime is `O(num)` (where `O` stands for a **pessimistic** case). But in case of algorithm that operate on numbers things get a little bit more tricky (thanks for noticing  thegreatcontini and Chris)! We always describe complexity as a function of input size. In this case the input is a number `num` and it is represented with `log(num)` bits. So the input size is of `log(num)`. Because `num = 2 ^ (log(num))` then your algorithm is of complexity `O(2^k)` where `k = log(num)` - size of your input.

This is what makes this problem hard - input is very, very small and any polynomial from `num` leads to exponential algorithm ...

On a side note @rici is right, you need to check only up to `sqrt(num)`, thus easily reducing the runtime to `O(sqrt(num))` or more correctly `O(sqrt(2) ^ k)`.

Comment: You should also note that prime factorization algorithms usually have their time complexity expressed in terms of the size of the number to be factored (in bits), rather than in terms of the number.  So this is really O(2**k) time.

Comment: Chris Dodd makes an important point that is often overlooked, so I just second his statement: this is exponential time because the length of the number is k=log(n), so the running time is actually 2**k.